# Putting text next to a kmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I want to put the equation next to the kmap, but it seems the kmap is located higher. How can I align the text and the kmap to start at the same height?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
table nodes/.style={
   rectangle,
   draw=black,
   align=center,
   minimum height=7mm,
   text depth=0.5ex,
   text height=2ex,
   inner xsep=0pt,
   outer sep=0pt
},      
table/.style={
   matrix of nodes,
   row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
   column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
   nodes={
       table nodes
},
execute at empty cell={\node[draw=]{0};}
}
}


$a$:
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix (kmap) [every node/.style={anchor=base},table,text width=10mm,name=kmap]
   {
    \node (a11){1}; & \node (a12){}; & \node (a13){1}; & \node (a14){1}; \\
    \node (a21){1}; & \node (a22){1}; & \node (a23){}; & \node (a24){1}; \\
    \node (a31){1}; & \node (a32){1}; & \node (a33){1}; & \node (a34){1};  \\
    \node (a41){}; & \node (a42){1}; & \node (a43){}; & \node (a44){1};  \\
   };
   \draw (a12.north west) -- ++(0,.3) node (lx3) {};
   \draw (a13.north east) -- ++(0,.3) node (rx3) {};
   \draw (lx3.north) to node[midway,above]{$x_0$} (rx3.north);

   \draw (a21.north west) -- ++(-0.3,0) node (lx4) {};
   \draw (a31.south west) -- ++(-0.3,0) node (rx4) {};
   \draw (lx4.west) to node[midway,left]{$x_1$} (rx4.west);

   \draw (a14.north east) -- ++(0.3,0) node (lx5) {};
   \draw (a24.south east) -- ++(0.3,0) node (rx5) {};
   \draw (lx5.east) to node[midway,right]{$x_3$} (rx5.east);

   \draw (a41.south west) -- ++(0,-.3) node (lx2) {};
   \draw (a42.south east) -- ++(0,-.3) node (rx2) {};
   \draw (lx2.south) to node[midway,below]{$x_2$} (rx2.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
   $a$ & $=$ && $x_3 \overline{x_0}$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_2 x_1$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $\overline{x_2}\; \overline{x_1}$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_3 \overline{x_1}$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_3 x_2 x_0$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_3 \overline{x_2}\; \overline{x_1}$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: result so far]

Added a second picture to clarify
[image: result I wish for]

Answer (score 1):

By default TiKZ pictures are aligned with their bottom point being aligned with baseline of surrounding text, but you can change this behaviour with `baseline` option. As an example, if you want to align them through center point can use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center), ...
```

Just changing this line in your code the result is:

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
table nodes/.style={
   rectangle,
   draw=black,
   align=center,
   minimum height=7mm,
   text depth=0.5ex,
   text height=2ex,
   inner xsep=0pt,
   outer sep=0pt
},      
table/.style={
   matrix of nodes,
   row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
   column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
   nodes={
       table nodes
},
execute at empty cell={\node[draw=]{0};}
}
}


$a$:
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
   \matrix (kmap) [every node/.style={anchor=base},table,text width=10mm,name=kmap]
   {
    \node (a11){1}; & \node (a12){}; & \node (a13){1}; & \node (a14){1}; \\
    \node (a21){1}; & \node (a22){1}; & \node (a23){}; & \node (a24){1}; \\
    \node (a31){1}; & \node (a32){1}; & \node (a33){1}; & \node (a34){1};  \\
    \node (a41){}; & \node (a42){1}; & \node (a43){}; & \node (a44){1};  \\
   };
   \draw (a12.north west) -- ++(0,.3) node (lx3) {};
   \draw (a13.north east) -- ++(0,.3) node (rx3) {};
   \draw (lx3.north) to node[midway,above]{$x_0$} (rx3.north);

   \draw (a21.north west) -- ++(-0.3,0) node (lx4) {};
   \draw (a31.south west) -- ++(-0.3,0) node (rx4) {};
   \draw (lx4.west) to node[midway,left]{$x_1$} (rx4.west);

   \draw (a14.north east) -- ++(0.3,0) node (lx5) {};
   \draw (a24.south east) -- ++(0.3,0) node (rx5) {};
   \draw (lx5.east) to node[midway,right]{$x_3$} (rx5.east);

   \draw (a41.south west) -- ++(0,-.3) node (lx2) {};
   \draw (a42.south east) -- ++(0,-.3) node (rx2) {};
   \draw (lx2.south) to node[midway,below]{$x_2$} (rx2.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
   $a$ & $=$ && $x_3 \overline{x_0}$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_2 x_1$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $\overline{x_2}\; \overline{x_1}$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_3 \overline{x_1}$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_3 x_2 x_0$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_3 \overline{x_2}\; \overline{x_1}$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example (aligning in cells temporary commented, but to uncomment):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
table nodes/.style={
   rectangle,
   draw=black,
%   align=center,
   minimum height=7mm,
   text depth=0.5ex,
   text height=2ex,
   inner xsep=0pt,
   outer sep=0pt
},      
table/.style={
   matrix of nodes,
   row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
   column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
   nodes={
       table nodes
},
execute at empty cell={\node[draw=]{0};}
}
}


$a$:
\begin{tabular}{cl} % PS
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix (kmap) [every node/.style={anchor=base},table,text width=10mm,name=kmap]
   {
    \node (a11){1}; & \node (a12){}; & \node (a13){1}; & \node (a14){1}; \\
    \node (a21){1}; & \node (a22){1}; & \node (a23){}; & \node (a24){1}; \\
    \node (a31){1}; & \node (a32){1}; & \node (a33){1}; & \node (a34){1};  \\
    \node (a41){}; & \node (a42){1}; & \node (a43){}; & \node (a44){1};  \\
   };
   \draw (a12.north west) -- ++(0,.3) node (lx3) {};
   \draw (a13.north east) -- ++(0,.3) node (rx3) {};
   \draw (lx3.north) to node[midway,above]{$x_0$} (rx3.north);

   \draw (a21.north west) -- ++(-0.3,0) node (lx4) {};
   \draw (a31.south west) -- ++(-0.3,0) node (rx4) {};
   \draw (lx4.west) to node[midway,left]{$x_1$} (rx4.west);

   \draw (a14.north east) -- ++(0.3,0) node (lx5) {};
   \draw (a24.south east) -- ++(0.3,0) node (rx5) {};
   \draw (lx5.east) to node[midway,right]{$x_3$} (rx5.east);

   \draw (a41.south west) -- ++(0,-.3) node (lx2) {};
   \draw (a42.south east) -- ++(0,-.3) node (rx2) {};
   \draw (lx2.south) to node[midway,below]{$x_2$} (rx2.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
& % PS
\begin{tabular}[b]{cccc}
   $a$ & $=$ && $x_3 \overline{x_0}$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_2 x_1$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $\overline{x_2}\; \overline{x_1}$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_3 \overline{x_1}$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_3 x_2 x_0$\\
   $$   && $+$ & $x_3 \overline{x_2}\; \overline{x_1}$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular} % PS

\end{document}
```

[image]

For better aligning you may add  space after he last line of your tabular e.g. by adding an optional parameter to `\\`.